# Adding my account url to top headers issue

Tags: layout, customer-account, header

I want to add to top header an url with myaccount if the user is logged in.
This is my xml

```
<block type="experius_linkmanager/link_list" name="linkmanager.topnav" as="topMenu">
    <action method="setIdentifier"><key>hoesjes-topmenu</key></action>
    <action method="insert"><blockName>cart_sidebar</blockName></action>
</block>
```

This is the code from header.phtml.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
```

Comment: Use <customer_logged_in>

Comment: can you give me an example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<customer_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
            <label>Custom Home Link</label>
            <url>home</url>
            <title>Custom Home Link</title>
            <prepare/>
            <urlParams/>
            <position>10</position>
        </action>
    </reference>
</customer_logged_in>
```

In above code you use your link.

Comment: I tried nothing shows up

Comment: i have updated my code please use above code to add link.if you are try to call child block in header use <reference name="header"></reference>

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<customer_logged_in>
        <!-- Your Block -->
    </customer_logged_in>
```

Comment: Do I have to create a block for this ?

Comment: you need a cms page right after login only it display right